# how to generate incremental string in sql-server which contain some default char plus some digits

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i want to generate unique string which contain default char and 4 digits.

for example-

```
"AKL0001"
"AKL0002"
"AKL0010"
```

like this.

Comment: Generate for what? For a select statement? For an insert? Update?

Comment: Supported SQL Server versions have SEQUENCE objects. Which version are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
WITH cte AS 
( SELECT 1 AS Num
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Num + 1
  FROM cte
  WHERE Num < 10000
 )
 SELECT 'AKL'+RIGHT(CONCAT('0000',Num),4)
 FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can change the options as you need:

```
DECLARE @min bigint, @max bigint, @string VARCHAR(12)
SELECT @Min=1 ,@Max=1000, @string = 'AKL'

SELECT TOP (@Max-@Min+1) @string + RIGHT(@Min-1+row_number() over(order by t1.number) + 1000 * @max, 4) as N
FROM master..spt_values t1 
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
```